# Replace Vgg16 FC layer with UNet

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to remove FC layer of VGG16 and add UNet layers. I don’t know how I can fine tune VGG16.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56193038/last-fc-layers-in-vgg16

Answer (score 0):

Unet is for Image translation, whereas VGG16 is for Image classification. You replace vgg16 fc layers by unet layers.

Anyways, This is how you can remove the fc layers of vgg16 and fine-tune your model,

Define VGG16 model with `include_top=False` to remove the fc layers

```
vgg16 = keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(input_shape=(224,224,3), include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

Then, use `vgg16.trainable = False` to freeze the layers.

Now, define your own model and use `vgg16` as feature extractor
for example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(vgg16)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu')  
model.add(Dense(8, activation='softmax')
```

Now, the summary of the model given by `model.summary()` would be,

```
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
vgg16 (Functional)           (None, 7, 7, 512)         14714688  
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_2 (Flatten)          (None, 25088)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 32)                802848    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 8)                 264       
=================================================================
Total params: 15,517,800
Trainable params: 803,112
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
_________________________________________________________________
```

Now you can compile and fit with your data to fine-tune this model.

Answer (score 0):

---

Thanks alot for detailed answer. I tried to print the model summary but it said me to build model first. Then I tried to compile model and define model input as vgg16.input and output as vgg16. as output. In model summary it was mentioning as model_1 instead of sequential model and there were 0 trainable params. I am unable to post code because its giving me error in posting may be because of wrong indentation.

I fit this model on my 3D Data, it extract the features. But when I tried to save it in dataframe it gives me error (ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1488, 7, 7, 8))

Resultant Features for single image are like this:
finish 1032
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 540ms/step
[[[[6.38653398e-01 2.02880692e-05 5.99825435e-05 1.21887595e-07
3.60443801e-01 1.75449770e-08 6.53681054e-04 1.68692059e-04]
[9.85548079e-01 7.78597954e-04 6.51674636e-05 1.28552932e-02
2.57301940e-06 1.99333044e-05 2.58037704e-04 4.72265616e-04]
[9.95418668e-01 3.13399983e-06 2.87542747e-07 4.47111670e-03
4.79741175e-07 3.33578015e-07 9.68128370e-05 9.19987178e-06]
[1.63317010e-01 6.28367705e-11 1.15235980e-06 1.02376181e-03
8.35411489e-01 4.00710887e-09 1.55429851e-04 9.12122996e-05]
[9.35774005e-05 1.01485979e-10 1.10866029e-06 9.62217450e-01
7.07163755e-03 5.90099735e-05 3.56038637e-03 2.69968603e-02]
[9.59551811e-01 4.48596802e-05 2.73983878e-05 2.33420674e-02
1.32198650e-02 9.62406048e-04 2.34712823e-03 5.04459254e-04]
[9.99982238e-01 4.59793046e-06 8.85845737e-12 5.71115200e-09
1.31434072e-05 2.44201426e-12 4.12060874e-09 4.05980333e-10]]

```
[[9.95615244e-01 3.53653104e-06 4.18960204e-04 9.37127770e-05
3.63768822e-06 2.30651058e-05 3.81550402e-03 2.63186284e-05]
[2.19437666e-02 9.60381996e-10 5.99338227e-06 2.13321403e-01
1.63183977e-09 1.63899801e-06 7.61410892e-01 3.31628183e-03]
[1.05815129e-02 5.36842706e-13 4.65415155e-07 9.74010408e-01
1.67039627e-06 9.23667098e-09 9.31831356e-03 6.08768407e-03]
[6.21392846e-01 2.81578455e-10 1.34801428e-06 3.78108501e-01
1.17762456e-05 1.14337240e-07 1.28620741e-07 4.85272234e-04]
[9.99988198e-01 2.88270140e-13 1.06488929e-09 5.52908568e-06
5.82322718e-06 4.06775143e-07 7.55641372e-13 8.57361127e-11]
[9.99999881e-01 1.54605725e-13 1.32699366e-13 2.19701427e-12
3.24160609e-08 1.47507421e-07 8.68404520e-15 1.41449074e-18]
[9.99988317e-01 7.39743257e-07 2.08591597e-08 3.57890855e-07
1.01329324e-05 3.77399312e-09 1.97229767e-07 2.44027319e-07]]

[[1.13353257e-04 7.41319752e-08 8.14688804e-07 6.34582015e-03
1.80785730e-06 5.15732568e-10 9.93498564e-01 3.95792486e-05]
[9.99952435e-01 7.21420292e-07 1.26446380e-07 8.54267981e-08
1.25725208e-10 4.65103985e-05 1.04982995e-07 2.35276468e-11]
[8.58553290e-01 1.28908595e-09 1.01818882e-08 1.53069698e-06
1.40553445e-01 7.75705150e-04 1.16072988e-04 3.01420555e-10]
[5.14177859e-01 3.27013076e-05 5.08953744e-05 4.06983756e-02
4.24867421e-01 1.34739248e-05 1.98230948e-02 3.36182537e-04]
[9.99999285e-01 3.82574882e-15 2.07914652e-19 4.74645966e-15
6.85358486e-07 4.67754191e-09 9.55586996e-15 1.04004281e-19]
[9.73042130e-01 1.16300402e-13 1.15553307e-16 1.38598348e-13
2.68260762e-02 1.31769149e-04 2.13823981e-09 1.42838703e-21]
[6.58826590e-01 1.14370661e-03 2.71215523e-03 7.10488437e-03
3.27758878e-01 2.98021419e-04 1.01155951e-03 1.14424620e-03]]

[[4.72898711e-04 4.25201688e-06 5.96813661e-05 1.09753758e-03
4.91514392e-02 9.07602347e-03 9.27107036e-01 1.30311595e-02]
[8.36947858e-01 1.07748428e-06 7.42213797e-06 1.65293876e-10
1.63002566e-01 5.08171388e-06 1.37384095e-05 2.22442668e-05]
[9.99180496e-01 6.13125684e-09 1.04616573e-08 1.44813821e-13
7.98821158e-04 2.06147106e-05 1.00973892e-07 5.70918833e-12]
[3.06183666e-01 7.12537300e-03 6.48844019e-02 2.82171527e-07
2.60606378e-01 3.54590029e-01 6.57759141e-03 3.22983506e-05]
[9.06643927e-01 2.92241180e-06 4.25770239e-04 1.02464046e-05
2.77019311e-02 6.34697527e-02 1.74534414e-03 3.84745763e-10]
[9.94718373e-01 3.48137474e-09 1.40934063e-07 2.90974644e-09
5.14680333e-03 5.18578490e-05 8.28195480e-05 7.00710269e-13]
[2.36748725e-01 1.28461523e-02 4.61331069e-01 1.62072517e-02
1.41178578e-01 1.62665278e-03 8.32319260e-02 4.68295738e-02]]

[[6.37385845e-01 4.78122502e-07 1.37834547e-06 2.81146235e-08
1.18766096e-04 3.54818851e-01 7.65525550e-03 1.94007753e-05]
[9.04297292e-01 9.33399025e-10 8.57405080e-09 1.72023076e-10
9.56908390e-02 7.96810866e-08 5.29237409e-09 1.18292410e-05]
[9.65073526e-01 4.98108228e-13 2.26485714e-13 8.48323659e-19
3.49259079e-02 5.92647609e-07 3.34810901e-10 2.65504198e-17]
[5.54283766e-08 4.74699339e-16 1.77488513e-08 9.92390323e-15
9.99906182e-01 3.26605125e-08 9.38145749e-05 8.06747724e-11]
[5.73852472e-03 1.56076985e-05 1.44343629e-01 3.08962569e-07
5.14853001e-01 1.22485556e-01 2.12562978e-01 3.42035406e-07]
[9.99987483e-01 1.15470256e-09 3.84308152e-07 3.59167918e-09
1.17577478e-07 1.05222744e-05 1.46735670e-06 3.61845970e-10]
[9.91667926e-01 7.44503486e-05 1.01070746e-05 6.01074089e-06
5.45765692e-03 1.44164206e-03 1.00829499e-03 3.33901902e-04]]

[[9.99976516e-01 2.12335927e-08 2.44374868e-11 4.90566687e-14
1.85316767e-05 3.11313374e-06 1.89475543e-06 1.88924565e-09]
[8.69753957e-01 6.94128435e-12 9.46339743e-11 2.25920238e-09
1.30242124e-01 1.71661213e-07 1.38845701e-06 2.46356558e-06]
[6.09741881e-02 2.91568814e-08 6.33201136e-09 1.24241069e-12
9.38653231e-01 3.47710797e-04 2.46832442e-05 1.40745393e-09]
[9.65304375e-01 5.42137819e-12 4.16872093e-15 1.99302908e-16
2.62953900e-03 3.15223038e-02 5.43761242e-04 2.34946924e-08]
[9.99999762e-01 1.69428129e-17 1.96970333e-15 7.79398563e-22
1.61234161e-15 5.50997803e-10 2.61878483e-07 2.89353993e-15]
[9.99998331e-01 8.35367779e-15 7.49791118e-10 1.49876127e-14
1.57211154e-11 1.00533715e-09 1.66164773e-06 1.71007617e-14]
[7.95299888e-01 3.93584809e-09 3.14216138e-08 9.37843048e-09
1.89878672e-01 1.77769461e-08 1.48213049e-02 4.91423684e-08]]

[[9.33954537e-01 1.20973964e-04 1.14206324e-08 1.40171471e-06
6.00965977e-05 9.53610140e-07 6.58588707e-02 3.16920477e-06]
[9.99959469e-01 1.13300862e-13 1.41840463e-11 3.10680043e-05
6.35626995e-10 8.57502584e-07 1.42984035e-07 8.45882550e-06]
[9.98554051e-01 3.87483638e-13 2.52303654e-08 8.05722156e-09
5.34030914e-05 2.30311663e-08 9.89229535e-04 4.03299549e-04]
[1.31540317e-02 1.90780975e-06 1.72623041e-10 2.25340080e-10
5.03390027e-07 4.64845244e-15 9.86843646e-01 1.78412185e-09]
[2.04621449e-01 2.54608722e-06 1.00194529e-06 1.23633625e-04
3.02570657e-09 1.04778031e-09 7.95251131e-01 2.15082252e-07]
[9.99889493e-01 1.61989137e-11 1.87405689e-07 1.75819496e-05
3.97604083e-09 9.12943215e-05 9.07707631e-10 1.42147223e-06]
[4.88181453e-04 1.86133953e-08 1.92044300e-08 1.33892484e-02
3.55223455e-02 3.14264037e-09 9.50586915e-01 1.32504765e-05]]]]
finish 1033
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fit model on my data using suggested changes. Features are now extracted and saved in dataframe and as a csv file. When I tried to give it to classifier it gives error on training on these features. Error was got 6 columns instead of 8 or got 9 columns instead of 8. The problem was in values in csv file. The command used in training classifier was on this line
X_train = genfromtxt(X_train_file_path, delimiter=',')
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
Line #2 (got 7 columns instead of 8)

Secondly, Can you please guide me in adding encoder decoder blocks of unet.